# IE's visual filters not displaying within the WebBrowser control

Tags: browser

all. Is there anyway to get IE's visual filters to render when using the WebBrowser control? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought the WebBrowser control was based on IE4 or 5.  It wouldn't know how to handle filters.